# Android Studio err: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle, television

i was working on my project and suddenly this error occurred, since then i am not able to compile the code without the following error.
ps: usually after getting this error rerunning my computer solves the problem but not this time.
moreover, i didn't update android studio for a long time.

error message:

```
16:04:05.420 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Android resource linking failed
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Output:  C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4379: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) @color/.
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   error: failed linking references.
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   
16:04:05.421 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Command: C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\45651725eebfca1bd670ec591f5de16e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --manifest\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -o\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
16:04:05.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -R\
16:04:05.423 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           @C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
16:04:05.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --auto-add-overlay\
16:04:05.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --java\
16:04:05.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
16:04:05.426 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --custom-package\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           com.example.android.tvleanback\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -0\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           apk\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --preferred-density\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           xhdpi\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --output-text-symbols\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --no-version-vectors
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Output:  C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0.aar\9a40ab0f382cc4894fcd86c823a3a43a\res\values\values.xml:2514:5-2571:13: AAPT: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) @color/.
16:04:05.427 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   error: failed linking references.
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Command: C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\45651725eebfca1bd670ec591f5de16e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --manifest\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -o\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -R\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           @C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
16:04:05.428 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --auto-add-overlay\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --java\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --custom-package\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           com.example.android.tvleanback\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           -0\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           apk\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --preferred-density\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           xhdpi\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --output-text-symbols\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
16:04:05.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]           --no-version-vectors
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
16:04:05.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
16:04:05.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
16:04:05.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)

16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
16:04:05.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Output:  C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4379: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) @color/.
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] error: failed linking references.
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Command: C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\45651725eebfca1bd670ec591f5de16e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --manifest\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -o\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
16:04:05.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -R\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         @C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --auto-add-overlay\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --java\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --custom-package\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         com.example.android.tvleanback\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -0\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         apk\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --preferred-density\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         xhdpi\
16:04:05.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --output-text-symbols\
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --no-version-vectors
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Output:  C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0.aar\9a40ab0f382cc4894fcd86c823a3a43a\res\values\values.xml:2514:5-2571:13: AAPT: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) @color/.
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]     
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] error: failed linking references.
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Command: C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\45651725eebfca1bd670ec591f5de16e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --manifest\
16:04:05.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -o\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -R\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         @C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --auto-add-overlay\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --java\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --custom-package\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         com.example.android.tvleanback\
16:04:05.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         -0\
16:04:05.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         apk\
16:04:05.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --preferred-density\
16:04:05.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         xhdpi\
16:04:05.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --output-text-symbols\
16:04:05.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
16:04:05.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --no-version-vectors
16:04:05.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
16:04:05.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:527)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)

16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
16:04:05.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
16:04:05.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
16:04:05.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
16:04:05.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
16:04:05.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
16:04:05.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
16:04:05.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
16:04:05.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Output:  C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4379: error: expected color reference but got (raw string) @color/.
16:04:05.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] error: failed linking references.
16:04:05.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Command: C:\Users\flip\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\45651725eebfca1bd670ec591f5de16e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
16:04:05.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
16:04:05.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         @C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --auto-add-overlay\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --custom-package\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         com.example.android.tvleanback\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         apk\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --preferred-density\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         xhdpi\
16:04:05.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --output-text-symbols\
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         C:\Users\flip\Desktop\android app\androidtv-Leanback-master2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]         --no-version-vectors
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 43 more
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:04:05.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
16:04:05.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
16:04:05.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

My build.gradle file:

```
android {


        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.tvleanback"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recommendation:recommendation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback-preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-leanback:2.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:1.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'

   implementation 'com.vliolios:themoviedb-java-kit:0.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Can you run `./gradlew :app:processDebugResources --stacktrace` from the command line and post the results? That should give us additional insight to the root cause.

Comment: check post update, please